# Showing values in two different colums based off a joining ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a select statement for SQL Server, as per the title.
My data is:

```
ID | JoiningID | Value | 

1 | 1 |  10

2 | 1 | 11

3 | 2 | 10

4 | 2 | 10

5 | 3 | 15

6 | 3 | 9
```

I'm trying to output three columns which would look like:

JoiningID | Column1 Value | Column2 value

```
1 | 10 | 11

2 | 10 | 10

3 | 15 | 9
```

The condition of this is that it needs to be within the select statement as opposed to within a where statement.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what if there are more than 2 values for a joiningid?

Comment: @vkp           Apologies, there is never any more than 2 values.

Comment: What determines which value should be in `Column1 Value` and which should be in `Column2 value`?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the values and then use `pivot` or conditional aggregation:

```
select joiningid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by joiningid order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by joiningid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do..

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE JoiningID IN(SELECT JoiningID from TABLE2)
```

or..

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE JoiningID NOT IN(SELECT JoiningID from TABLE2)
```

Or, you could do a JOIN or LEFT JOIN..